# OOP in python: how to make a method getting called like instance.method.variant()

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm new to Python and particularly I'm inexperienced within OOP.

I'm working on plotting tool for som matfiles in python for some data for a power converter.

I will try and explain my question without getting too much in details.

As of right now I have made a class called Plotter and an method called plot_by_name().

In plot_by_name() I can type all the names that are included in the dictionary, this could for example be ['UL1', 'UL2', 'UL3']. 
Now I would like to make some special methods that uses plot_by_name() for the most frequent combinations, so instead of having to type the following:

```
ratehigh1 = Plotter(dictionary)
ratehigh1.plot_by_name(['UL1', 'UL2', 'UL3'])
```

The user could simply type:

```
ratehigh1 = Plotter(dictionary)
ratehigh1.plot_by_template.UL()
```

And furthermore I imagine that the user could get suggestions from its IDE for these frequent combinations. I hope this part explains why it would be convenient, so that the user wouldnt have to recall each specific name but instead just choose of the suggestions.

So my question is whether it possible to get a structure of the class such that the user could call instance.plot_by_template.combination()? 
- What would combination be to plot_by_template? (subclass, method or something else)

Comment: how about returning an object with a "combination" method from plot_by_template?

Comment: How would the user then call the function for a specific combination?

Answer (score 0):

In Python this is not possible, as you write. You cannot call a function within a function from outside. But you can use a pattern with `re` (e.g. `plot_by_name("UL")`).

Comment: Technically it is possible. To get 'instance.method.variant()' though you would have to define 'method' to be a class constant rather than a function, which is then a member of another class which has a 'variant' method. So that would be hacky and discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The particular syntax `instance.method.variant()` is not idiomatic in Python. However, you can accomplish what you want in a more idiomatic fashion using class constants:

```
class Plotter:

    PLOT_TEMPLATES = {
         "UL": ['UL1', 'UL2', 'UL3'],
         "OTHER": ['some', 'other', 'thing']
    }

    def plot_by_name(self, name):
        // ... Your Code Here ...

    def plot_by_template(self, template):
        if template not in self.PLOT_TEMPLATES:
            raise RuntimeException(f"Plotting template not found: {template}")
        self.plot_by_name(PLOT_TEMPLATES[template])
```

Alternatively, assuming there are only a small number of possible templates, that are all known statically, a good way to do it would just to implement different methods for each template. This also has the advantage of giving the user suggestions in the IDE (in most IDEs), which you wanted. Something like this:

```
class Plotter:

    def plot_by_name(self, name):
        // ... Your Code Here ...

    def plot_by_template_UL(self):
        self.plot_by_name(['UL1', 'UL2', 'UL3'])

    def plot_by_template_OTHER(self):
        self.plot_by_name(['some', 'other', 'thing'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! That's very very helpful!